# how to lookup image in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a Picture Library created with photos. In my Custom List, I want to create a lookup field to a Picture in my Picture Library and a description field. This I figured out by linking to the ID of the image in the Picture Library. How can I display that image as a thumbnail using my custom list? (Is it also possible to display a thumbnail or preview of the picture in my custom list since it know the ID of the picture?).

Comment: You will get a lot more answers when you start to: **(1)** answer the questions for clarification posted in comments, **(2)** upvote and accept the answers that helped you. Right now we get no feedback from you and it feels like talking to a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some javascript so that when you mouseover a list item in your custom list a modal window opens up with an image preview?